# Replacing the Page Number in Certain Index Entries with `ib.'

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, idxlayout

Is there a simple way to have the page number of an index entry indicated by *ib.* when the previous entry specifies the same page number; for example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
%Sentence\index{Heading@{\scshape{Heading}}}
\newpage Another sentence\index{Heading@!Entry-i}
\newpage Another sentence\index{Heading@!Entry-ii}
\newpage Another sentence\index{Heading@!Entry-iii}\index{Heading@!Entry-iv}

\newpage
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Produces the output:

[image]

I would like to have, for example, *Entry-iv, 3* appear as *Entry-iv, ib.*

THANK YOU.